# How to check for foreign key reference records before deleting parent table record sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have to do the following scenario on deleting a record from the Sql server table.

When I am trying to delete a record from Table (TableA) If that record is not referenced by any table than only that record has to be deleted otherwise if any other table record having reference to this record I have to update a column called Obsolete in table (tableA) has to be updated.

For this scenario I want to check whether that record is referenced by any other tables in the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below given code

```
Create Table Parent
(
    ID INT Identity primary key,
    val varchar(10),
    IsObsolete bit not null default(0)
)

create table child
(
    CID INT Identity,
    ID INT CONSTRAINT [FK_Parent_ID] REFERENCES Parent(ID),
)

INSERT INTO Parent(val) values('a'),('b'),('c')

insert into child(id) values (1),(2)

-- NOW SUPPOSE I WANT TO DELETE RECORD B

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM child WHERE id = (select id from parent where val='b'))  -- this exists then update
BEGIN
    UPDATE Parent
    Set IsObsolete = 1
    Where  val='b'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Parent 
    Where  val='b'
END
```

Comment: This is happening where you know the tables and the references...
But how do you do that when you don't know how many FK it has a PK in all tables of a database?

Comment: Suppose I have a table "X" with a PK "IdCol", type int. I insert a record, so I have IdCol=1. Now I have table A1 with column 'IdColChild' int PK, and column 'IdMaster' as int FK to IdCol of X table. I insert 4 records in A1 table, so I will have 1,1, 2,1, 3,1 4,1...

Comment: I have 3 more tables like A1 (A2, A3 and A4), but I have 3 records referenced to X table, column IdCol in table A2 and also 5 records referenced to the same X table, column IdCol in table A4. The A3 table has no records inserted yet. Which is the stored procedure or recursive select or whatever some instructions, to give me that I have in this moment 12 records in other tables where the PK IdCol has references?!
I think I made me clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a view with this select:

```
SELECT        FK_Table, FK_Column, PK_Table, PK_Column, PK_Alias = CASE WHEN PrevVal = PK_Table THEN PK_Table + ltrim(str(RowNumber)) ELSE PK_Table END
FROM            (SELECT        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FK_Table) AS RowNumber, lag(PK_Table) OVER (ORDER BY FK_Table) PrevVal, LEAD(PK_Table) OVER (ORDER 
                         BY FK_Table) NextVal
FROM            (SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT FK.TABLE_NAME AS FK_Table, CU.COLUMN_NAME AS FK_Column, PK.TABLE_NAME AS PK_Table, 
                                                    PT.COLUMN_NAME AS PK_Column
                          FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS C INNER JOIN
                                                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN
                                                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN
                                                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN
                                                        (SELECT        i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
                                                          FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS i1 INNER JOIN
                                                                                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                                          WHERE        (i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY')) AS PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME) x) p
```

This view it will give me all the foreign keys. I use PK_Alias for codding joins when I have to join the same table more than once (for other purpose, not here).

Now I use this little stored procedure to return a dataset with all tables and number of rows for each one where the PK has references:

Edited: ***Constraints*** represent the view

```
create procedure mvp_CountRowsForFKs
@PKColumnName varchar(100),@ColumnValue sysname
as
begin

    set nocount on

    declare cCurs cursor fast_forward for
    select FK_Table,FK_Column
    from Constraints
    where PK_Column=@PKColumnName

    declare @Result table (table_name varchar(100),Counted int)

    declare @TN varchar(100),@CN varchar(100),@Command varchar(300)
    open cCurs
         fetch next from cCurs into @TN,@CN
         while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            begin
                set @Command = 'SELECT '''+@TN+''',Count(*) as Counted from '+@TN+' where '+@CN+'='+str(@ColumnValue)   
                insert @Result exec(@Command)
                fetch next from cCurs into @TN,@CN
            end
    close cCurs
    deallocate cCurs

    select table_name,sum(Counted) Counted from @Result  where Counted<>0 group by Table_Name
end
```

When you use the same PK in two or more FK, the view will give you the same FK table more than once, so the @Result variable table will store the same table more than once, according to presence of records in FK columns :)

PS: I suppose PK Column it is of type Integer

Example of use:

```
exec mvp_CountRowsForFKs 'IdUser',34
```

It will return something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an oldie but I came across it and thought I'd add to the mix...

If you've got the appropriate foreign key constraints applied (and you're not using `ON DELETE CASCADE`), you'll get an exception if you try and delete the row.  Now using exceptions to control the normal execution flow is considered poor practice because exceptions are expensive - but then so are database commands!  And I couldn't come up with a better way.  So here's my C# based approach:

```
try {
    // code to execute the delete here
}
catch (SqlException ex) {
    if (!SqlErrors.IsForeignKeyConstraintError(ex)) {
        throw;
    }
    // could not delete, do something else...
}
```

And just so we can tell the difference between an actual  FK exception and some other SQL exception, here's my class:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace My.Funky.Namespace {

    public static class SqlErrors {

        // From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645611.aspx
        // also: select * from sys.messages where language_id=1033 and severity between 11 and 16

        private enum Errors {
            None = 0,
            ForeignKeyConstraint = 547,
            RaiseError = 50000
            // ...there are 12K+ messages - so not putting them all here!
        }

        public static bool IsForeignKeyConstraintError(SqlException ex) {
            return ex != null && (from object err in ex.Errors select err as SqlError).Any(err =>
                       err.Number == (int)Errors.ForeignKeyConstraint ||
                       err.Number == (int)Errors.RaiseError
                   );
        }
    }
}
```

Admittedly the poster does not mention C# but in all likelihood the original problem is entirely moot by now - and someone else might find it useful! :o)

(and I expect it'd be pretty easy to implement something similar in T-SQL)